# Unzipping a zipped folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, zlib, unzip, gunzip

I zipped a folder in nodejs with code :

```
fstream = require('fstream'),
tar = require('tar'),
zlib = require('zlib');
fstream.Reader(toZipDetails) /* Read the source directory */
         .pipe(tar.Pack()) /* Convert the directory to a .tar file */
         .pipe(zlib.Gzip()) /* Compress the .tar file */
         .pipe(fstream.Writer(zipOutDetails)); /* Give the output file name */
```

Then i unzipped it with :

```
fs.createReadStream(inFileName)
                .pipe(zlib.Gunzip())
                .pipe(tar.Extract({ path: "C:\\temp\\extract" }))
                .on("end", function () {
                    alert("done");
                });
```

The folder name is `toZip` with file `a.txt`.

I wanted a folder toZip with a.txt in `extract` folder, but

i got a `a.txt file in extract folder`.

How can i get the `toZip` folder ?

Comment: long time no comments :(

Comment: I think there's some dirty work you should do to achieve it. archiver may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
var unzip = require('unzip')
var fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('<<.zip folder path>>').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: <<save unzipped data path>> }));
```